# Checkbox input returning empty string instead of true/false, using React hook dom and material-ui FormControlLabel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to print the values returned from a form. This is the snippet for the Checkbox part.

```js
<FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox  {...register('remember')} name="remember" color="primary" defaultValue={false} />}
              label="Remember me"
            />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

However, upon submit I'm getting the result as-

{"username":"sdfs","password":"dfsd","remember":""}

instead of-
{"username":"sdfs","password":"dfsd","remember":true}

What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error here is because you are not actually passing a `checked` property to the `<Checkbox>` component

1. Create a `rememberMe` state using useState
2. Create a `handleChange` function
3. Pass both the checked state and handleChange to the `Checkbox` Component
4. Now you can use the rememberMe state in your submission

   ```
   const [rememberMe,setRememberMe] = useState(false);

   const handleChange = (e)=>{
    setRememberMe(e.target.checked)
   }

    <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox checked={rememberMe} onChange={handleChange} 
          name="remember" />}
          label="Remember me"
              />
   ```